# ASP.NET Tree View out of Sql Binding

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, treeview

I got a Categorie Table with a column for the Tree View in my Database which I want to display as a Tree View.

My TreeView Column Looks like the following. (I Hope you understand)

```
0001.
0001.0001.
0001.0002.
0001.0002.0001.
0001.0002.0002.
0001.0003.
0002.
...
...
...
```

Is this possible to be displayed in a asp:TreeView? Or what other way can I use to display this?

The Database already existed I'm just designing the website & can't do much in the database.

**EDIT:**

I tried the first Solutions and now I got this.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7LzG.png)

But I don't want to display the number, just the name and the number just as value invisible for me to use when I click on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication64
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable dt = null;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Index", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0001.", "aaaa"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0001.0001.", "bbbb"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0001.0002.", "cccc"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0001.0002.0001.", "dddd"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0001.0002.0002.", "eeee"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0001.0003.", "ffff"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0002.", "gggg" });

            new Index(dt);

            MakeTreeRecursive(0, Index.indexes, null);
            treeView1.ExpandAll();

        }
        public void MakeTreeRecursive(int level, List<Index> rows, TreeNode parent)
        {
            TreeNode child = null;

            var groups = rows
                .OrderBy(x => x.paragraphs[level])
                .GroupBy(x => x.paragraphs[level]);

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                child = new TreeNode(group.Key);
                if (parent == null)
                {
                    treeView1.Nodes.Add(child);
                }
                else
                {
                    parent.Nodes.Add(child);
                }

                foreach (Index node in group.Where(x => x.paragraphs.Count == level + 1))
                {
                    child.Nodes.Add(node.row.Field<string>("Value"));
                }
                List<Index> descendants = group.Where(x => x.paragraphs.Count > level + 1).ToList();
                if (descendants.Count > 0)
                {
                    MakeTreeRecursive(level + 1, descendants, child);
                }

            }
        }
    }
    public class Index
    {
        public static List<Index> indexes { get; set; }
        public List<string> paragraphs { get; set; }
        public DataRow row { get; set; }

        public Index() { }
        public Index(DataTable dt)
        {
            Index.indexes =  dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x => new Index() {
                    row = x,
                    paragraphs = x.Field<string>("Index")
                    .Split(new char[] {'.'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(y=> y).ToList()
                }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Here is solution if you only want the text

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable dt = null;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Index", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0001.", "aaaa" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0001.0001.", "bbbb" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0001.0002.", "cccc" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0001.0002.0001.", "dddd" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0001.0002.0002.", "eeee" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0001.0003.", "ffff" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0002.", "gggg" });

            new Index(dt);

            MakeTreeRecursive(0, Index.indexes, null);
            treeView1.ExpandAll();

        }
        public void MakeTreeRecursive(int level, List<Index> rows, TreeNode parent)
        {
            TreeNode child = null;

            var groups = rows
                .OrderBy(x => x.paragraphs[level])
                .GroupBy(x => x.paragraphs[level]);

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                Index root = group.OrderBy(x => x.paragraphs.Count).First();
                child = new TreeNode(root.row.Field<string>("Value"));

                List<Index> descendants = group.Where(x => x.paragraphs.Count > level + 1).ToList();
                if (descendants.Count()  > 0)
                {
                    MakeTreeRecursive(level + 1, descendants, child);
                }
                if (parent == null)
                {
                    treeView1.Nodes.Add(child);
                }
                else
                {
                    parent.Nodes.Add(child);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public class Index
    {
        public static List<Index> indexes { get; set; }
        public List<string> paragraphs { get; set; }
        public DataRow row { get; set; }

        public Index() { }
        public Index(DataTable dt)
        {
            Index.indexes = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x => new Index()
                {
                    row = x,
                    paragraphs = x.Field<string>("Index")
                    .Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(y => y).ToList()
                }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your Solution. The only thing that didn't work was parent/child.Nodes. I changed it to parent/child.ChildNodes and that gave a result. But I don't want to display the number, just the name and the number just as value invisible for me to use when I click on it. -> See Image in my Quesiton.

Comment: And is there a way to make it Lazy load? Because the database has a really bad structure, all categories together are about 14'000 Rows, even though all Items are only about 5'000. And now if it loads 14'000 every times it reloads it takes too long.

Comment: To eliminate the "Value" just remove the for loop where "Value" is added to the tree.   When a form application runs slow I usually put the code in a backgroundworker so it doesn't lock up the form.

Comment: I don't want to remove the Text, I want to remove the number

Comment: So you want the aaaa, bbbb

Comment: Yes it should be like a category tree view where aaaa and bbbb are categories.

Comment: Hi thanks alot for your help. Because of the Loading speed. I'm not working in a Form Application but on a ASP.Net Website & the page now loads really slow every time.

Comment: I saw a recommendation a few weeks ago with a treeview  to add all the children first before putting children in to the TreeNode to speed up results.  So if we move some code around it may work faster.  Look at my edits.